# If $m^*(E)=0$ prove $m^*(f(E))=0$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and $f'$ is bounded function.  Show that if  $m^*(E)=0$, then $m^*(f(E))=0$

---

let $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty }A_n$, since  $m^*(E)=0$ $E$ is bounded

Because $f$ is continuous, $f(E)$ its also bounded.

$f(E)\subseteq (M-\frac{1}{n},M+\frac{1}{n})$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R} $ $\Rightarrow$ $m^*(f(E))\leq m^*((M-\frac{1}{n},M+\frac{1}{n}))=\frac{2}{n}$,
now if I let $n \rightarrow \infty$ I get what I want.

I know my solution is wrong (since I am not even using the differentiability of $f$) and has some holes and wrong statements, but that's the best I could do, my idea was  somehow  to end up with something like $m^*(f(E))<ε $

Comment: Note that $f$ continuous and $E$ bounded does not imply $f(E)$ bounded. Take $f(x)=1/x$ and $E=(0,1)$ as a counterexample. However, once you insist on a bounded derivative, things change.

Comment: More generally, if $E$ is bounded and $f$ is *uniformly* continuous, then $f(E)$ is also bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint(s):

- Suppose $f$ is a Lipschitz function, i.e. there is some constant $C>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le C|x-y|$. Use this to get a bound on the measure of $f(I)$ in terms of $m(I)$ whenever $I$ is an interval. It's useful to remember that $f(I)$ must be an interval.
- Use that $f'$ is bounded to show that $f$ is Lipschitz.

In more detail,

> If $x,y\in I=(a,b)$, then $|x-y|< b-a=m(I)$, so $|f(x)-f(y)|\le C|x-y|\le Cm(I)$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(I)$ is an interval, hence its length can be no longer than $C(b-a)$.
>  Now, given any set $E$ of measure $0$ and $\varepsilon>0$, cover $E\subset \bigcup_n I_n$ so that $\sum_n m(I_n)<\varepsilon$. Then $f(E)\subset \bigcup_n f(I_n)$ and $m(f(I_n))\le C m(I_n)$, so $m^*(f(E))\le C\varepsilon$.

Comment: ohh $E\subset \bigcup_n I_n$ so that $\sum_n m(I_n)<\varepsilon$ I totally missed that, also I didn't encounter that if $f'$ is bounded then it's Lipschitz, although pretty easy, I would never think about using that, anyway thanks a lot.